# wxPython: Vertical BoxSizer containing two StaticTexts; another separate horizontal BoxSizer containing buttons, keep overlapping on the top corner

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I am working on a GUI desktop app project using `wxPython`. On the startup screen I need to show two panels side by side. The left one will hold a picture and the left panel will display some static texts and buttons. My issue here is with the right panel.

I want to show the company name, its address, and login/new user buttons on the right panel. I've defined a VERTICAL `BoxSizer` (`vbox_org_name_address`) to hold the two `StaticText`s-- company name and address. Below that, a HORIZONTAL `BoxSizer` holds the two buttons. A VERTICAL `BoxSizer` (named `main_sizer`) holds all these inside the panel: one BoxSizer containing StaticTexts, another containing the two buttons.

Below is the desired layout:
[image: desired-layout]

But what I'm getting is this:
[image: result]

I've tweaked the code multiple times but could not arrange the layout as I wish to. Below is my code:

```
class HomePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # define the panel          
        right_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
    
        # define the sizers
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox_org_name_address = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)       
        hbox_buttons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    
        # define the StaticTexts
        org_name = wx.StaticText(right_panel, label='ABC Pharmaceuticals Wholesale')
        address = '66B, Tower Street...Contact: +91 1234 8899'
        address_label = wx.StaticText(right_panel, label=address)
        
        # add the company name and address to the sizer
        vbox_org_name_address.Add(org_name, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
        vbox_org_name_address.Add(address_label, 0, wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
       
        # define the buttons
        login_btn = wx.Button(right_panel, label="Login")
        add_user_btn = wx.Button(right_panel, label="Add User")

        # add the buttons to the sizer
        hbox_buttons.Add(login_btn, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, 10)
        hbox_buttons.Add(add_user_btn, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, 10)
       
        # add the two sizers to main_sizer
        main_sizer.Add(vbox_org_name_address, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        main_sizer.Add(hbox_buttons, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed adding the `main_sizer` to the panel.
This is it:

```
# add the two sizers to main_sizer
main_sizer.Add(vbox_org_name_address, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
main_sizer.Add(hbox_buttons, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)

# add the sizer- 'main_sizer' to the panel- 'right_panel'
right_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

self.SetAutoLayout(True)
self.Layout()
```

Result:
[image: correct-result]